# How to get current time and date and set a specific time for action to take place in my app

Tags: java, android, time

My app gains points everyday at 0000 Hours in the midnight, So i want to set this time and when the time reaches, the set time i want my app to add points automatically even if the app is not opened.

I tried below code but it is not working

```
//creates a time for 0000am
    String newDayTime = "00:00:00";
    Date date = java.sql.Time.valueOf(newDayTime);
    Calendar newDayDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    newDayDate.setTime(date);
    if(((today.getTime().after(newDayDate.getTime())))){
        dataa.edit().putFloat("blToday", blToday(select.this) + 15f).apply();
    }
```

The problem with this code is, it does not add point when 12:00am reaches, and the app also adds point everytime i launch it, every time when i open the app it adds points, How can i correct my code?

Comment: please study alaram manager in android

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: What do you mean by "gains points" ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `ScheduledExecutorService`.  It will execute the submitted task (Runnable/Callable) at the scheduled time and also the task can be repeated periodically.

Create a Task like below:

```
class UpdatePointWorker implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // write your code here to update the ponints
        // dataa.edit().putFloat("blToday", blToday(select.this) + 15f).apply();
    }
}
```

Schedule the task like below:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Long midnight = LocalDateTime.now().until(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(), ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
    Runnable task = new UpdatePointWorker();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, midnight, 1440, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very time sensitive task you should use `AlarmManager`, which will execute at the specified time regardless of system conditions. If you can afford flexibility, you can/should use `JobScheduler`. However the key principle of `JobScheduler` is that it will decide when the best time to execute your job is. You can't guarantee a delay of {x} minutes.

Example of an alaram manger

```
Calendar sixCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    //set the time to 6AM
                    sixCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
                    sixCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                    sixCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AutoStartUp.class);   
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sixCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Here is your broadcast recevier class

```
 public class AutoStartUp extends BroadcastReceiver{


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           specificMethod();// your method will be call here

    }
    }
```

Don't forget to register it mainfest

```
 <receiver android:name=".AutoStartUp"
                          android:enabled="true"
                        > 
                </receiver>
```

Comment: Can you show me AlarmManager code sir, I do not want delays it has to be perfect

Comment: From this code I am not able to add my method which is suppose to add points

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Bera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50777964/642706) is close to correct, but chooses not quite the right *java.time* classes & methods.

## `ZonedDateTime` & `Instant`, not `LocalDateTime`

It incorrectly uses the `LocalDateTime` class which lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So a `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a specific moment on the timeline.

Instead, use `ZonedDateTime` to represent a specific moment with the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date and a time-of-day. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witching_hour_(supernatural)) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Extract the date-only portion, without a time-of-day and without a time zone. Any *java.time* class named “Local…” means it is “unzoned”, without any concept of zone or offset.

```
LocalDate ld = now.toLocalDate();  // Extract date-only without time-of-day and without offset-from-UTC.
```

Avoid thinking/talking about “midnight” as that becomes a slippery concept. Instead, focus on “the first moment of the day”. So we need the first moment of tomorrow.

Determine “tomorrow”.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

Let *java.time* determine the first moment. Do not assume that will be the time-of-day 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean the day may start at a time such as 01:00:00. Specify a time zone, of course, to handle any anomalies affecting the people of this region, this time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime tomorrowStart = tomorrow.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Calculate the span of time from now until then, the start of tomorrow. The `Duration` class represents a span of time unattached to the timeline.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( now , tomorrowStart ) ;
```

By the way, it may help your understanding to see those values in UTC. As a programmer (or sysadmin), you should be thinking in UTC. Forget about your own parochial time zone while on the job.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instantNow = now.toInstant() ;
Instant instantTomorrowStart = tomorrowStart.toInstant() ;
Duration d = Duration.between( instantNow , instantTomorrowStart ) ;
```

That pair of `Instant` objects represent the very same moments as the pair of `ZonedDateTime` objects. Same points on the timeline, but different wall-clock time. So the resulting `Duration` calculation is the same.

## `ScheduledExecutorService::schedule`, not `scheduleAtFixedRate`

The other Answer is correct in suggesting `ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule a task to be run at a certain time.

But the other Answer calls [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which repeatedly executes the same task (a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)). But the Question specifies the requirement that the task be run at the first moment of the day, everyday. That time of day may change on various dates, because of anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) or other changes to the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) used by the particular [time zone.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) These changes happen surprisingly often as politicians around the world show a proclivity to making these changes. So if you really mean to check the first moment of the day, then you need to recalculate the waiting duration each and every time your run the task.

So you should ask your executor service to run the task only once. And at the end of that task, schedule another run for the following day.

Set up your executor service, and save a reference to it somewhere in your app. The [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class provides many such services. Get a count of either `SECONDS` or `NANOS` from generic `Duration::get` method. Using nanoseconds is a bit silly as an executor is *not* guaranteed to run with such precision. There is a always a fudge-factor involved, as the load on your CPU’s cores, your host OS’ multi-tasking scheduling, your JVM’s threading, all may impact when your task actually gets run. So I use seconds here.

By the way, a bit of [greybeard](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/greybeard) advice… Midnight is the [witching hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witching_hour_(supernatural)) on computers. This is when many OSes and apps engage in clean-up and roll-over activities such as making fresh log files. Some programmers and sysadmins choose to run a little while *after* midnight, or later in the middle of the night such as 2 or 3 AM.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
```

Calculate a delay until the first execution.

```
long countUntilNextTaskRun = d.getSeconds() ;
```

Schedule the task by calling [`ScheduledExecutorService.schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) and passing the amount of time to wait.

```
executorService.schedule( myRunnableOrCallable , countUntilNextTaskRun , unit ) ;
```

You may want to capture the `ScheduledFuture` for later use.

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = executorService.schedule( myRunnableOrCallable , countUntilNextTaskRun , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

This task will run only once. After that task does its main job have it also schedule the next run by using the same code seen above. Calculate the time until the next start-of-day in that particular time zone.

### Lifecycle

The executor service lives in memory of your app. This has two important implications:

- Be absolutely sure to shutdown the executor service. Otherwise, the thread pool and scheduled task may remain in memory even after your app has closed (depending on the implementation of your JVM and host OS). So your app should always detect when it is closing/exiting, and shutdown the executor service.
- The executor service is not persisted after your app closes/exits. So when your app launches, your initialization/startup code must re-establish a fresh executor service.

If your business requirements ask that you catch-up on missed days of task-runs, then you will also need to program your task to record in some persistent manner the date-time (`Instant`) when it last ran. Then you calculate how many days you missed using the same kind of classes and methods discussed above.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: May you make it a code in one class form I am not good at coding so I get lost where exactly to put the code, onCreate() or where?

Comment: From this, where do I put my method to add points at midnight?

Comment: @tinoe Sorry, but that’s your job, not mine. If you need more help, search Stack Overflow. You will find *much* coverage of both Android and of the Java executors. Indeed your whole Question could probably be closed as a duplicate.